# Disabling save dependent on file location

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet that is saved in two seperate locations, my personal folder (z:\docs\trial.xlsm) and a networked folder(t:\allusers\docs\trail.xlsm). I need to stop the networked copy being edited and saved using VBA. Both local and networked are identical copies.

I have tried the following script

Private Sub on workbook_open

```
Dim noedit As script: noedit = "t:\allusers\docs\trail.xlsm"
Dim t
t = ThisWorkbook.Path

If Z = t Then
```

...... and that's where I am getting stuck.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the `ThisWorkbook` module and use this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim noedit As string: noedit = "t:\allusers\docs\trail.xlsm"

    Cancel = (noedit = ThisWorkbook.Path)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for that. Unfortunately every time I try this all i get is an Error 91 and it highlights the noedit="t:\allusers\docs\trail.xlsm" field.

Comment: @user3888911 sorry, I'd left it as `script` but it should be `string`. thanks for the edit